# How to use Naive Bayes for Named Entity Recognition

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to program Named Entity recognition for a low resource language from the scratch. To start I would like to use Naive Bayes. 
My little Google search suggest me that it is widely used for text classification using naive bayes.
Can it be used to solve NER problem. Any suggestion/direction regarding this would be appreciated. I prefer Python language.

Other methods for solving the problem of NER from starts for a new language are also welcome.

Comment: Actually programming it sounds like less work than finding references.

Comment: I don't see how it could work very well, though. Do your texts regularly contain new hapaxes? How would you resolve those? They could be either/or.

Comment: You could check http://www.nltk.org/ if you haven't. [naivebayes](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html)

Comment: Why Naive Bayes? Naive Bayes assumes all columns are independent, which sounds like it wouldn't work so well for NER.

Comment: A CRF is surprisingly easy to train given the labeled training data and assuming you have a clue what features are useful for your sequence tagging task. Take a look at CRFSuite.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue of classifying named entities. Now we are able to classify named entities using Naive Bayes classifier. What helped us is customized feature extractor.

If you are using nltk you should have a look here : http://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/dev/